# Evaluation metrics for cluster or cox process

Tags: r, spatial, model-comparison, poisson-process, spatio-temporal

I am working with spatial point processes and on a dataset which seems to be a non-homogeneous poisson point process. I have fitted a cluster/ cox process model and also used this model to predict the intensities in certain locations using the `spatstat` package in `R`.

I have built several models and I want to compare these models using an evaluation metric or need some sort of a metric that compares the accuracy of the intensities. Any idea how to approach this issue?

Comment: Maybe you can improve the quality of your post by inserting your R-Code

Comment: If you think it is a non-homogeneous Poisson point process, why do you fit a cluster/Cox process (which is not Poisson, but has clustering of the points)?

Comment: @EgeRubak Yes, I have used cluster process but while calculating the intensity using spatstat package in R I am getting the same results as the one using non-homogeneous Poisson point process. I have used the function predict.kppm for "cif" which fits the intensity similar to what we get by using predict.ppm function and so the confusion!